# What is the advantage of using Kruskal coordinates?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, astrophysics, mathematical-physics

(as opposed to Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates) The EF coordinates already take care of the coordinate singularity so I dont see a point for using Kruskal coordinates.

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal–Szekeres_coordinates) reminds you they cover the entire spacetime, as [E-F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddington–Finkelstein_coordinates) stresses in its penultimate paragraph. Read up.

Comment: The coordinate singularity cannot be removed by a coordinate transformation: “the singularity of $M$ at $r=R_s$, where the tangent space of $M$ is perpendicular to the coordinate space $R^3$, is essential, and cannot be removed by any coordinate transformations. The coordinate transformations such as those given by Eddington and Kruskal possess the singularity as well, and, consequently, cannot be used as the coordinate systems for the metrics” - https://www.newton.ac.uk/files/preprints/ni14098.pdf

Comment: “the singularity on the boundary of black holes is essential and cannot be removed by any differentiable coordinate transformation with differentiable inverse. The Eddington and Kruskal coordinate transformations are non-differentiable, and are not valid.” - Same link.